# Constructing a biholomorphism onto a unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

In my lecture notes from complex analysis there is the following problem:

Find a biholomorphism from $D = \{z : 0< Arg(z) < \phi \}$ to the unit disk.
Basically, my idea is to find a biholomorphism to the upper halfplane and then use $\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ map to get to the disk. However, I am not sure how to get to the upper halfplane? My idea was to just take the map $z \rightarrow z^{\pi/2\phi}$ but I am not sure if I will have the boundary of the halfplane?
Am I on the right track?

Comment: You don't need the boundary. Your reasoning is correct.